# Difficulty identifying x argument, for html_nodes function

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm running the following text....

```
read_html("https://www.travelmath.com/flying-time/from/Canada/to/Germany")
html_nodes(html,"#flyingtime")
```

to extract the flight time. however I keep running into this error

```
"Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "function"
```

I've tried using html_text, html_attr, html_nodes etc.. with no luck

```
read_html("https://www.travelmath.com/flying-time/from/Canada/to/Germany")
html_nodes(html,"#flyingtime")

"Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "function"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `read_html` call is running but you aren't saving the results any where (especially not a variable called `html`). So you can either save the value and pass it to the next function

```
html <- read_html("https://www.travelmath.com/flying-time/from/Canada/to/Germany")
html_nodes(html, "#flyingtime")
```

or you can pipe the results into the next function

```
read_html("https://www.travelmath.com/flying-time/from/Canada/to/Germany") %>%
  html_nodes("#flyingtime")
```